# how to fix batch response: resouce not found issue when using git push with LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

When I use git push to push the source code with large files, shows error like this:

```
> git push
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: Resource not found
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/RedDwarfTech/cv_render.git'
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? is it possible to ignore the resouce? I have tried the force option, but did not work. This is the git track config:

```
> git lfs track
Listing tracked patterns
    *.otf (.gitattributes)
    *.ttf (.gitattributes)
    config/font (.gitattributes)
Listing excluded patterns
```